# Is it possible to reference the "agent" container from a declarative Jenkinsfile later in a script section?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've got a Jenkinsfile that uses the declarative syntax, and uses `agent { dockerfile }` to build the execution environment. I also have a set of tests that need a database to run against, so I need to use sidecar containers, which aren't available in the declarative syntax, so I'm using a `script` step to set up that part.

I'd like the tests to run in the same environment, but I haven't found a way to reference the container that was built by the `agent { dockerfile }`. Is there something I can use to get at that container? As a simplified example:

```
pipeline {
    agent
    {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile.ci'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.image('postgres:10-alpine').withRun() { pg ->
                        docker.image("$reference_agent_container_here").inside("--link ${pg.id}:database") {
                            echo 'Run some tests that need a database'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could stick the container in a registry and reference it in both places, but I like that the Dockerfile and the Jenkinsfile are both referenced from source control at build time, so there's no way for them to be out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is not possible, at least with the current state of declarative pipelines. I ended up rewriting the the job as a scripted pipeline, so that I could use `docker.build()` at the beginning of the job and use the returned container ID to reference it later in the pipeline.